# JavaScript how to find data of array of object without giving exact search value that matches with value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

How to make a function that finds data of array of object without giving exact search value that matches with value of object.

For example my array is :

```js
const array = 
[{
    "name": "Max Messi",
    "age": 21,
    "gender": "male"
},
{
    "name": "tina baidya",
    "age": 10,
    "gender": "female"
},
{
    "name": "tina shrestha",
    "age": 100,
    "gender": "female"
}
]
```

Now i want a function to return all the data that has `name` "tina" in it.

I tried using `array.filter()` method but it requires exact search name. Like i need to type `tina shrestha` instead of just `tina`

this is what I had tried:

```js
const array = 
[{
    "name": "Max Messi",
    "age": 21,
    "gender": "male"
},
{
    "name": "Lina baidya",
    "age": 10,
    "gender": "female"
},
{
    "name": "tina shrestha",
    "age": 100,
    "gender": "female"
}
]
function findData(data, id){
    const found = data.filter(element => element.name === id)
    return found
}
console.log(findData(array, "tina"))//logs empty array as i need to type full search value
```

So how can i make the function that searches json data without putting exact value.

Comment: Use filter() and indexOf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to check if the name [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) your string, rather than being equal to it:

```
const found = data.filter(element => element.name.includes(id))
```

Comment: This is a great solution, just keep in mind that it's case-sensitive!

Comment: @ManuelAbascal yes, so i changed all the strings to lower case by `toLocaleLowerCase()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the **[includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** method like so:

```
const array = [
    {
        "name": "Max Messi",
        "age": 21,
        "gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lina baidya",
        "age": 10,
        "gender": "female"
    },
    {
        "name": "tina shrestha",
        "age": 100,
        "gender": "female"
    }
]

const findData = (data, searchParam) => {
    return data.filter(element => element.name.includes(searchParam.toLowerCase()));
}

const results = findData(array, "tin");

console.log(results);
```

However, it won't work if you search for example `tina2` or `tinathy` so it doesn't cover all edge-cases!

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @NabyelAbascal this solution will help me alot, but is there any way to make it work even if i search `tina2` or `tinaaaa`

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial I'll do some research, I'm not sure about it right now!